# firestore how to allow a second tab to open

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, persistence

I'm trying to open a new tab for the same localhost:8100 web app.
I authenticated the user like this:

```
signinUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<firebase.User> {
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE)
      .then(function() {

        console.log("signing in");

        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
      });

  }
```

but when I open another tab I get "there's another tab open with offline persistence" error.
Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, this is not an Auth error. Are you using Firestore by any chance?

Comment: yes.  AngularFirestore

Comment: The issue is Firestore related. You should update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I did this before. You have to make two FIRESTORE instances. Put the first one in try catch, then when you have the second tab error do a normal FIRESTORE instance without offline capabilities.

FIRESTORE offline only works in one tab

Comment: Thank. How do I disable offline capabilities?

Comment: just not turn on offline capabilities